# how can I add arguments to the body GET request in groovy?

Tags: http, groovy, jmeter, get, jsr223

Im newbee here and I wanna create GET request in JSR223 Jmeter with arguments. How i can add it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wch7H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp4c4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add them to your [URL query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms)

```
def get = new URL("http://localhost:8080/calculator/basic/add?addend=3&augend=2")
```

More information: [How to Send Groovy HTTP and HTTPS Requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-http-request)

By the way, why don't you use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler instead, you will get metrics like [Connect Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) and response handling out of the box for free, will be able to use [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) and so on.

Comment: Okay I did it in http request but i cant do it in jsr223.

Comment: But It doesnt work in jsr223. Its just API application (Calculator) and i need to get response. In response I got only "sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://localhost:8080/calculator/basic/add?addend=3&augend=7"